# Displaying Data after Time Interval in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller

Here is the Link for the jsFiddle : [AngularJS : Display Data](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/ucm1c1zv/)

I have HTML File is like following:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">         
    <div ng-repeat="test in tests">
           <p>{{test.testName}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller under .js file is like following:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.tests = [{
        "testName" : "Test-1 : Windows Test"
        }, 
        {
        "testName" : "Test-2 : Linux Test"
        },          
        {
        "testName" : "Test-3 : Unix Test"
        }, 
    ];
}
```

**My Question is:**

Currently the result is coming in the following format:

```
Test-1 : Windows Test
Test-2 : Linux Test
Test-3 : Unix Test
```

I want to display the `Test-1 : Windows Test` at beginning and after 30 seconds `Test-2 : Linux Test` and after 30 seconds `Test-3 : Unix Test` and so on..!!

Once all the data are completed again the `Test-1 : Windows Test` will come again..!!

How should I implement this with the AngularJS ?

Comment: you may need to use `ngAnimate` with `$interval`

Comment: @pankajparkar , You are correct. and OP please see my answer. i hopes my answer will solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using set time interval (  ***$interval*** in angular.js) . I don't know how can i explain to you. But i will give my code with *fiddler*, You can see what i am did.

*So try this below way instead of your code.*

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <p>{{testName}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

*Javascript changes*

The below code working by eache 30 second( i don't know exactly 30 second), But you can put what time you need

```
    angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller("myCtrl",["$scope","$interval",function($scope, $interval){
        $scope.tests = [{
            "testName" : "Test-1 : Windows Test"
            }, 
            {
            "testName" : "Test-2 : Linux Test"
            },          
            {
            "testName" : "Test-3 : Unix Test"
            } 
        ];
         var count=0;                    
         $interval(function(){                         
                $scope.testName=$scope.tests[count].testName;
                 count=count+1;
                if($scope.tests.length==count){
                  count=0;
                }                               
         },30000);   // I don't know it's exact 30 seconds     
    }]);
```

Sample [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ucm1c1zv/28/)

I have updating proper code for you.

Comment: can you please update your code to use `app.controller` which would be the more correct way of doing code

Comment: Okay wait few seconds